# How can I set bounds for a Django Model DateField?

Tags: django, validation, date, django-models

In my `model`:

```
birth_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='D.O.B')
```

How can I set bounds for this, such as:

```
01-01-1990 to (current date - 18 years)
```

I'm assuming there's a way to set this in the model so it's included by default in forms, but I've never used dates in a project before, so I'm not sure how this is done.

It would be useful to know how to do this with `DateTimeField` and `TimeField` if it isn't the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTimeField` and `TimeField` do not have options to set lower and upper bounds. However, it is possible to write [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#module-django.core.validators) for any type of field.

A validator to check the date of birth would look something like:

```
from datetime import date
from django.core.exceptions import ValidatonError

def validate_dob(value):
    """Makes sure that date is been 1990-01-01 and 18 years ago."""
    today = date.today()
    eighteen_years_ago = today.replace(year=today.year - 18)
    if not date(1990, 1, 1) <= value <= eighteen_years_ago:
        raise ValidationError("Date must be between %s and %s" % (date(1990,1,1,), eighteen_years_ago)
```

Then use your validator in your model field.

```
birth_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='D.O.B', validators=[validate_dob])
```

Comment: Is the date value that will be passed to the validator the same regardless of localisation?

Comment: For a `DateField` value will be a `date` object. Localisation only affects how you display a date as a string, not the date itself.